# Convert data of type time inside array to int or float. Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'numpy.str_'

Tags: django, numpy, datetime, time

Convert data of type time inside array to int or float. Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'numpy.str_'

```
def ProdGrafico(request):
    ## Dados Media Duracao do Forno
    mediaForno = Relatorioresumido.objects.all()
    divideForno = len(mediaForno)
    listMediaForno = []

    for x in range(int(divideForno)):
        y = mediaForno[x].duracaoforno
        y = datetime.strptime(y, '%H:%M:%S')
        listMediaForno.append(y)

    try:
        mediaForno = listMediaForno[0] + sum((listMediaForno_i - listMediaForno[0] for listMediaForno_i in listMediaForno), timedelta(0)) / len(listMediaForno)
        print(mediaForno)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        mediaForno = 00
```

Comment: please format your question properly

Comment: Show the full error with traceback.  Identify which variables are giving the problem.  The error says that you are trying to 'add' a number and an array with `string` dtype.  Which is the string?

Comment: @user273970 show the model, it will be easier to understand.